# Как оценить погрешность?

Tags: c++, численные-методы

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#define PI 3.1415926535

/*----подинтегральная функция---*/
double INTEGR(double x)
{
    return exp(-(x*x)/2) ;
}

/*----Интегрирование методом трапеции---*/
double Trapez(double left, double right, double h)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double runner;

    /*Формула трапеции*/
    for(runner = left + h; runner < right; runner += h)
    {
        sum += INTEGR(runner) ;
    }

    sum = (sum +  0.5*(INTEGR(left) + INTEGR(right)) ) * h;

    return sum * 1 / sqrt(2 * PI);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    double a, b;
    double h;

    std::cout << "Нижнее значение интеграла: " ;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "Верхнее значение интеграла: ";
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << "Шаг интегрирования: ";
    std::cin >> h;

    std::cout <<"Ответ по методу трапеции: " << Trapez(a, b, h) << std::endl; 
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Собственно, как оценить погрешность такого вычисления ? :)

Функция Лапласа (не удвоенная).

Comment: Думаю, вопрос скорее не к нам, а на маткод.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точность вычисления интеграла методом трапеций пропорциональна `delta*delta`, где `delta` величина интервала разбиения.

Пример вычисления точность смотрите [например здесь](http://mals.ts9.ru/8/815.htm)

В реальной жизни это обычно проще и быстрее сделать итерациями. Скажем задаться количеством разбиения отрезка интегрирования в `N` - вычислить значение интеграла для него, затем увеличить `N` в 2 раза и вычислить разницу между вычисленными значениями интеграла и так до тех пор пока разница не станет меньше требуемой точности.

Comment: Спасибо, но я решил обойтись ф-ой Котеса.